# Запятая между причастным оборотом и рядом неоднородных определений

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после причастного оборота?

купленная заводом (,) спеченная многогранная режущая пластина

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как все определения неоднородные. Причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым словом, дополнительного обстоятельственного значения не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо большое.